# Was history taught as an academic subject between 10th and 18th centuries to pupils?

Tags: education

The background of the question is kinda funky. Someone posited a theory that the reason they allow a ghost to tech history in Hogwarts, is that the magicals of Britain - who basically seem to keep to pre-18th century if not earlier cultural norms, simply consider History teaching another of the useless newfangled Muggle ideas, so they don't give a hoot.

However, "History" as a thing obviously is not newfangled, going as far back as Ancient Greece.

So the question is, was **teaching history to students** - especially in a *school* and not a university - a new thing since 18th century, or was that an established tradition between 10th and 17th century in Europe, especially England?

Bonus Q: If the answer is "no", were there exceptions? Universities? Custom prep for heirs of high level nobles?

The only result my Googling found that seemed even remotely promising was behind JSTOR paywall. Every other hit either didn't mention history as a subject at all, or simply said things were centered on theology (unsuspectingly) - but Bede was "theological" historian so I am not really sure that proves much. The fact that I'm looking at "history" as a subject in context of "history of education" makes almost any reasonable search far less obvious (honestly, in my mind at the moment, impossible)

Comment: I realize that even the idea of "schooling for all kids" wasn't exactly established till quite later in England, but I assume there was at least some schooling - church based or for nobles - done in earlier centuries.

Comment: @DVK you might start with [History of education in England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_education_in_England) for background.

Comment: `especially in a school and not a university` - `especially England` -- you might consider editing the title to reflect this limited focus of the question.

Comment: in the middle ages, Latin was often the 1st language taught (even because european languages were not standardized enough). Any literate person (and they could be a relevant number) would then be able to read at least some classical stuff. If one reads Virgil, Cicero, Cesar, Augustine, etc, does it count as studying history? e.g., Dante clearly read a lot about/from ancient Rome. Maybe you should ask about studying story as a separate discipline: I think not, it was quadrivium and trivium.

Comment: @MCW - the only result my Googling found that seemed even remotely promising was behind JSTOR paywall. Every other hit either didn't mention history as a subject at all, or simply said things were centered on theology (unsuspectingly) - but Bede was "theological" historian so I am not really sure that proves much. The fact that I'm looking at "history" as a subject in context of "history of education" makes almost any reasonable search far less obvious (honestly, in my mind at the moment, impossible)

Comment: @justCal - That Wiki didn't mention history NOT being taught, just like all the other resources I have seen. But absence of evidence is not evidence of absence

Comment: @Luiz - this was what I was trying to express by "taught as an academic subject". A separate subject specifically devoted to who/what/when/why happened in the past; not simply mentions of the past in unrelated study

Comment: I was providing that link more for clarification of the points in your first comment, when and how individuals received schooling during your listed time-frame.

Comment: During the time you are inquiring, the meaning of the word "history" undergoes a number of changes: 1. It always was strongly intertwinded with "story", and in a theological sense the proof of "rightness" was the doctrinal value of a story, not its accuracy. 2. Especially in the renaissance it was used as a general term for the systematic collection of knowledge - see for example [natural history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_history), which is not about the development of nature, but a term used broadly for the collection of knowledge about nature,

Comment: Not aware of a subject called 'history' with its own separate lessons and curriculum periods before the 19th Century, although the study of Latin and Ancient Greek did include the works of ancient historians like Tacitus and Thyucidides. There were books published and read about more modern history too. In 18th Century England or its American colonies a literate and knowledgeable person would have been expected to know that there had been an English Civil War, execution of King Charles I and Cromwellian Republic in the 1640s & 1650s. Regret can't be more detailed.